# Issues with TP Link AC1300 Archer T4U (2)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I had an issue with the dongle not getting recognized at all. After installing some drivers from github, now it is actually recognized, and even the WiFi icon in the top-right menu appears (without a name) and it fails to find any networks.

When I run

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

it finds the dongle, but it says *-network DISABLED

I've disabled Secureboot and it's UEFI, if that makes any difference. Someone knows how this issue can be handled?

rfkill list all results:

```
3: phy3: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: *Disabled* typically means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless radio. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 Done. Doesn't show blocked.

Comment: We need a full diagnostic work-up. Please follow the process here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180